# Truncated tree if there's newline before <DOCTYPE>

Tags: python, lxml

I've a page coming from some site, and lxml behaves strangely here.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun  3 2018, 00:45:25) 
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> with open('1.html', newline='') as fi: text=fi.read()
>>> etree.LXML_VERSION
(4, 2, 5, 0)
>>> text[:100]
'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US">\n<head id="ctl00_header"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" cont'
>>> len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text[1:])))
455129
>>> len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text)))
201176
>>> etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text))[-150:]
b'ors\',&#13;&#10;  \'brand\': \'Omron\',&#13;&#10;  \'variant"/></div</td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></div></div></div></div></form></body></html>'
```

In this case it looks like the parsing has abruptly stopped in the middle of the attr (it's onclick). I know everyone says DOCTYPE must be the first line, but I think this behaviour of lxml (or something underneath, I haven't tested) is confusing. So before filing a bug, maybe sonmeone knows what's this about?

Update: It's even more interesting. Another page.

```
(Pdb) p text[:20]
'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<ht'
(Pdb) p text[-20:]
'pt>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
(Pdb) len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text)))
316031
(Pdb) len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text.lstrip())))
259909
(Pdb) len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text.rstrip())))
316031
(Pdb) len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text.strip())))
259909
(Pdb) len(etree.tostring(etree.HTML(text.encode())))
316023
```

Comment: What is "some site"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: mouser.com. I would have attached this 1.html, but don't know how…

Comment: Ah, well, here it is. https://pastebin.com/fAsQ6sWQ

Comment: That is not an HTML document

Comment: It is: (venv) pooh@pooh ~/tmp/1 $ uudecode 1.uue|xz -cd|file -
/dev/stdin: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators